# Better diff color scheme

Tags: vimdiff

I've started using diff mode in vim at work, and the one thing I noticed is that the colors are really bright, which doesn't help when you're trying to look for differences in huge files for long periods of time.

Are there any color schemes out there that people have customized to make diff mode easier on the eyes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I quite like the diff colors in [my colorscheme](https://github.com/romainl/Apprentice):

[image: diff]

Comment: I can't find a proper how-to for installing your colorscheme. I am lost. Maybe it's obvious and I can't really see it. Could you help please?

Comment: Everything is explained in the README.

Comment: Does it support a light/bright flavor, too? When i use computer during sun shines i switch my terminal to light color scheme. @romainl
Looks promising, good work!

Comment: This colorscheme is great, but I agree with MycrofD that you could flesh out the install a little with maybe a mkdir and curl call.

Answer (score 13):

I have a syntax/diff.vim (that I source manually) with the following contents:

```
hi DiffText   cterm=none ctermfg=Black ctermbg=Red gui=none guifg=Black guibg=Red
hi DiffChange cterm=none ctermfg=Black ctermbg=LightMagenta gui=none guifg=Black guibg=LightMagenta
```

Comment: Something like this should be contributed upstream to VIM. The out of the box colors being completely unreadable because of near zero contrast  in diff mode is just silly.

Answer (score 6):

My own scheme "[Traffic light colors](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/vim-diff-traffic-lights-colors)" featuring red, yellow, green and blue.

They are a bit gentler in GVim than on the terminal.

But they were really designed to be intuitive (for westerners) rather than gentle.

[image: gvim]

[image]

Comment: It looks like the [JellyBeans](https://github.com/nanotech/jellybeans.vim) colorscheme also uses red, green and blue, although in a slightly different way.

Comment: Your scheme is nice, and I'm trying with it. It turns off language-dependent syntax coloring, what I start thinking is something necessary to assure the readability of the differences. +1

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Yes, I find language highlighting distracting when I want to focus on the changed characters. You can remove all `ctermfg=white` and `guifg=white` from the file, if you like.

Comment: If you _do_ disable the `white` foreground, you might want to consider setting a background colour instead. Why? If you have long lines but wrapping is off, then the red+yellow change could appear _off the screen_, and the changed line could easily be missed! I think that's why diffing themes tend to set some styling for the _entire line_. Oh, we are doing that already. We set the background to black, to draw the attention. (It's subtle, but it might be enough, as long as your Normal background is black though!)

Answer (score 4):

I went through all colorschemes that go with vim by default, and found 'morning' and 'zellner' look kind of OK for vimdiff.

Comment: Thanks, `morning` got me through a bind in dark mode tonight.